# OpenAPI generator inheritance in version 5

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

In previous version of open-api-maven-generator (4.3.1) I had inheritance with 1 field

```
 BaseField:
    type: object
    properties:
       id:
         type:integer
```

and used it to schemas where I needed it like

```
allOf:
    - $ref: 'BaseField'
```

And it was generated as inheritance

```
Schema extends BaseField
```

After version moved to 5. it becomes generated as injection

```
Schema {
// field of BaseField
Long id;
}
```

Is any way to back to inheritance?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3172

Comment: Which leads to https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#schemaComposition

Comment: @RobertHarvey makes sense. thanks